# Using LIKE for prepared statements

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I am trying to update a column in my table with a prepared statement. I have to use LIKE and wildcards but for some reason nothing it's not working. I tried a few different ways from this site and different ones. I'm trying to upgrade from a non prepared statement to a prepared one. This is how it originally worked:

```
$opened_query = mysqli_query($this->con, "UPDATE notifications SET opened='yes' WHERE 
user_to='$userLoggedIn' AND link LIKE '%=$post_id'");
```

This is how I'm trying to make it work:

```
$post_id = '%' . $post_id . '%';
    $opened_query = $this->con->prepare('UPDATE notifications SET opened="yes" WHERE 
        user_to = ? AND link LIKE ?');
    $opened_query->bind_param("si", $userLoggedIn, $post_id);
    $opened_query->execute();
    $opened_query_result = $opened_query->get_result();
```

I also tried the following blocks:

```
$post_id = '%' . $post_id . '%';
    $opened_query = $this->con->prepare('UPDATE notifications SET opened="yes" WHERE 
        user_to = ? AND link LIKE ?');
    $opened_query->bind_param("si", $userLoggedIn, $post_id);
    $opened_query->execute();
```

---

```
$post_id = '%' . $_POST['link'] . '%';
    $opened_query = $this->con->prepare('UPDATE notifications SET opened="yes" WHERE 
        user_to = ? AND link LIKE ?');
    $opened_query->bind_param("si", $userLoggedIn, $post_id);
    $opened_query->execute();
    $opened_query_result = $opened_query->get_result();
```

---

```
$likeVar = '%' . $_POST['post_id'] . '%';
    $opened_query = $this->con->prepare('UPDATE notifications SET opened="yes" WHERE 
        user_to = ? AND link LIKE ?');
    $opened_query->bind_param("si", $userLoggedIn, $likeVar);
    $opened_query->execute();
    $opened_query_result = $opened_query->get_result();
```

Comment: `$likeVar` is a string, and you bind with `i`. Use `bind_param("ss", ...)`

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Thanks. If you put it as an answer i'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your `$likeVar` variable.

With this statement, `$likeVar = '%' . $_POST['post_id'] . '%';` you set `$likeVar` to a `String`.

Whereas in your `$opened_query->bind_param("si", $userLoggedIn, $likeVar);`, you pass an argument as `i`, to treat `$likeVar` as an `Integer`.

Change your statement to replace the param type as `String (s)` and it should work:

`$opened_query->bind_param("ss", $userLoggedIn, $likeVar);`